# Upload file on ASP.Net Core returns empty Request.Form.Files, only on React

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, reactjs, asp.net-core

My Html

```
<form method="post" action="/Upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="files" multiple />
  <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="btn" />
</form>
```

My Action

```
[HttpPost("/Upload")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(){
    var files = Request.Form.Files;
    ...
}
```

This work as expected when loaded directly from my Html View, but if i load the exactly same Html using React:

```
render(){
  return(
  <form method="post" action="/Upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="files" multiple />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" className="btn" />
  </form>
  );
}
```

The post request works, but 'var files' is always a empty array.

Any idea whats wrong?
Thank you all in advance

Answer (score -1):

You should use `ICollection<IFormFile> files` or `IFormFile file` to handle files in asp.net core.

Comment: take a look at your network an see if the file is actually sendt at all